# Checkbox $viewValue showing as 'false' when checked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My default value for my checkbox is "true" and I'm using the checkbox's `$viewValue` elsewhere in the same form. At the onset of the app the checkbox's `$viewValue` is showing "false" even when the checkbox is checked, but only until the user toggles the checkbox off/on. [What's going on here?](http://jsfiddle.net/0qaeLb4e/)

**html**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <form name="testForm">
        <label>The Checkbox
            <input type="checkbox" name="testCheck" data-ng-model="testCheck" data-ng-checked="true"></input>
        </label>
    </form>
    <p>{{ testForm.testCheck.$viewValue }}</p>
</body>
```

**javascript**

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `ng-checked` with `ng-model` they wont work together well.Using ng-checked just sets the checked property on the checkbox it wont update `ng-model` automatically and the presence of checked property will mess up the initial model change.

Use controller to initialize model to true.

Ex:-

```
$scope.testCheck = true;
```

and just do:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="testCheck" data-ng-model="testCheck"></input>
```

You could use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to initialize the model from the view like:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-init="testCheck = true">
```

though it is not appropriate to use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for intializing properties other than for aliasing special properties if ng-repeat.