# select/ unselect checkbox angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'am facing a issue with Unselecting a checkbox, when the backend service fails. It still remians selected . Here is the flow of code

html -

```
> <ng-repeat="rx in rxList">
>     <button toggle-switch ng-checked="rx.details.autoFillActive" ng-model="rx.details.autoFillActive" ng-click="toggleReadyFill(rx,
> $event)" ></button>
```

Js file -

```
$scope.toggleReadyFill = function(rx, $event) {
           scriptsyncService.addRx(rxList, storeDetails, syncDate).then(
                function(success) {
                    console.log('success');
                },
                function(error) {
                    $scope.selectedRx.isSelected = false;
                });
        };
```

the issue over here is, when we select the checkbox, we are making service call and if the service fails the checkbox still remains selected. This is being unselected only on refresh of page. How can i unselect the checkbox upon service failure

Comment: ignore $scope.selectedRx.isSelected. My questions is how would i unselect it on service failure ?

Comment: @Zee What do you mean assigning the same to all? rx is the current item

Comment: @nikitha if isSelected is a property of an rx, you should bind that to ng-checked i would think and also you could just do rx.isSelected = false in the controller. selectedRx seems redundant as you're passing in the current rx

Comment: Another note apart from possible typo: [Do not mix ng-checked with ng-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353258/checkbox-viewvalue-showing-as-false-when-checked/30353327#30353327) .

Comment: @aw04. By bad. dint notice that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the value of `rx.details.autoFillActive` instead of `$scope.selectedRx.isSelected` because you are using this expression for `ng-model` and also `ng-checked`